# Can the subversion ruby bindings use the user's stored credentials?

Tags: ruby, svn, authentication, swig

I'm writing a cross-platform ruby script to manage some subversion repositories. I initially generated bash commands but this proved to be very Windows-unfriendly. I then rewrote my script to use the SWIG ruby bindings provided with subversion. This works perfectly (as far as SVN operations are concerned) on all required platforms (Ubuntu, Fedora, OS X, Windows) with ruby 1.8.7.

I use the [**svn_wc**](https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc) gem to abstract part of the bindings because I don't yet understand the low-level code.

Now, my problem is that I have to give the user's credentials to the bindings. **svn_wc** uses [this code](https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc/blob/master/lib/svn_wc.rb#L868):

```
ctx.add_simple_prompt_provider(0) do |cred, realm, username, may_save|
  cred.username = @svn_user
  cred.password = @svn_pass
  cred.may_save = false
end
```

If `@svn_user` and `@svn_pass` are nil, the bindings fail with a segmentation fault:

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/1.8/svn/util.rb:86:
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.8.0]

[1]    4381 abort      my_script.rb
```

If I comment this whole piece of code, my svn command fails with the following error:

```
cant get info: subversion/libsvn_ra_neon/util.c:608:
Svn::Error::RaNotAuthorized: OPTIONS of 'https://my.subversion.url':
authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server:
rejected Basic challenge (https://my.subversion.url) (SvnWc::RepoAccessError)
```

I don't know what the `may_save` parameter is for. Changing it to true and giving no credentials still produces the segmentation fault.

My script should use the stored, encrypted credentials the same way the command line binary does. I don't want to type the credentials every time or to store them in a unencrypted configuration file.

I have found no documentation about this. Does anyone know if it's possible and how?